# You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links - Count is off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, privileges

Last I checked 2 was not more than 2.

[image]

Comment: I assume you're talking about [this post](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/17831), which *does* have another inline link up above in the text. Is that one still there in your edited version? Because that would make three.

Answer (score 8):

The link counter includes all links, including bare links. I checked the logs and while you only used the add link button (or Ctrl-L) twice, you also included a bare link at the top of the post. That makes three links. In order to post, remove one of those links.